# How should I replace a value in JSON file with its md5 value using jq command?

Tags: shell-script, shell, json, hashsum, jq

I have a big log file containing a line as below example :

```
{"data_1":210,"target_number":1096748811,"extra_data":66}
{"data_1":0,"target_number":7130881445,"extra_data":56}
{"data_1":1712,"target_number":1098334917,"extra_data":48}
{"data_1":0,"target_number":3062674667,"extra_data":54}
{"data_1":53,"target_number":5110609228,"extra_data":246}
```

I want to replace **target_number**'s value with evaluation of `md5` value in **whole file**.

I am trying the `jq` command with basic syntax as below :

```
jq  '.target_number|= "md5(\(.))"' input2.log
```

**Expected output** is :

```
{"data_1":210,"target_number":620e25e6f054992308c564cb883e4940,"extra_data":66}
```

**Current output** is :

```
{"data_1":210,"target_number":md5(1096748811),"extra_data":66}
```

Comment: Calculate md5 of whole file in advance, store in shell variable, call `jq` with this shell variable.

Comment: @dirkt: OP wants the md5sum for the `target_number` field AFAIK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jq` does not have direct `md5` calculation function like it has for base64. You need to use the shell's utilities for that.

```
jq -c . input.log |
while IFS= read -r obj; do 
    md5sum=$( printf '%s' "$obj" | jq -j '.target_number' | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1)
    jq -c --arg md5 "$md5sum" '.target_number = $md5' <<<"$obj"
done > output.json
```

Note that the generated hash from `md5sum` cannot be interpreted as a number in `jq`, but only as a string value. So it will be enclosed in quotes.

Note that this approach is "expected" to be slower, because it involves invoking `jq` for each line of your input file separately and calculating the hash for the number.

Comment: where should I pass input file name ? can you mention `input.log`

Comment: @LuFFy: in the first line, Instead of json replace your filename

Comment: Slightly awkward `while` loop there. Would be better to call `md5sum` on each number and then somehow pair them up with `jq`. I started to look at that but ran out of time.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yes may be an assoc. array with bash like `map[number]=md5str` could work, but since `md5sum` calculation is external, reconstruction is anyway going to be cumbersome

Comment: shell output thrown error as : `line 1: $'\r': command not found`

Comment: @LuFFy: Run `dos2unix input.log` and re-run the command again

Comment: `dos2unix` succeed and run script again and got same error.

Comment: Where are you running this script? Linux or DOS? Can you post the output of `file input.log`. I've tested the command to run as expected. The file encoding in your input file seems to be causing these problems

Comment: I am using MobXterm, Am I missing something ?

Comment: @LuFFy: Problem is with your input file. Post the output of `file input.log`

Comment: @Inian Output : `input.log: ASCII text`

Comment: Got it working, had some junk space issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a jq inspired tool in python, which has access to all python functions.

```
$ pip install jf
```

With your data in test.jsonl

```
$ jf -c --import hashlib '{data_1: .data_1, target_number: hashlib.md5(str(.target_number).encode()).hexdigest(), extra_data: .extra_data}' test.jsonl
{"data_1": 210, "target_number": "620e25e6f054992308c564cb883e4940", "extra_data": 66}
{"data_1": 0, "target_number": "f83d74be3dcb71d53263aefdf08203a9", "extra_data": 56}
{"data_1": 1712, "target_number": "56ae797ad2c16813d1a6168d28b58d89", "extra_data": 48}
{"data_1": 0, "target_number": "81394a193503036fad53b8a9d6ca2456", "extra_data": 54}
{"data_1": 53, "target_number": "6f01490a5dc694e51a69b79f7dd21c24", "extra_data": 246}
```

Edit:
Or more simply

```
$ jf -c --import hashlib 'update({target_number: hashlib.md5(str(.target_number).encode()).hexdigest()})' test.json
{"data_1": 210, "target_number": "620e25e6f054992308c564cb883e4940", "extra_data": 66}
{"data_1": 0, "target_number": "f83d74be3dcb71d53263aefdf08203a9", "extra_data": 56}
{"data_1": 1712, "target_number": "56ae797ad2c16813d1a6168d28b58d89", "extra_data": 48}
{"data_1": 0, "target_number": "81394a193503036fad53b8a9d6ca2456", "extra_data": 54}
{"data_1": 53, "target_number": "6f01490a5dc694e51a69b79f7dd21c24", "extra_data": 246}
```